# One-sided fisher exact test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

|  | Outcome #1 | Outcome #2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Source #1 | a | b |
| Source #2 | c | d |

Let p1 denote proportion of outcome #1 for source #1, p2 denote proportion of outcome #1 for source #2. I'm trying to calculate P(odds(p1)>odds(p2)) with the Fisher's exact test.
Is this equivalent with doing a one-side Fisher's exact test with:
H0 - odds ratio <=1
H1 - odds ratio >1
and then calculating 1- [computed p-value]?